# Third Axis in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a graph with the following axis:

[image]
This graph works fine, but I need one more addition to it.

My question is this:

I need to get a third line on there with the total amount of units for each month. I have a field that I can pull that has this total by month, but how do I go about putting it on my graph? When I try to add it, it wants to do it by manufacturer, which is not what I want. I just need a single line that has this total amount of units. Do I need to add it to the axis under manufacturer or up top next to the market percent axis?

Answer (score 0):

It's a tad bit complicated, but this is what I would do:

1. Union the Total Units values to the Manufacturer % values and put it on a Secondary Axis. The data set would look something like this:

[image: dataset]

2. Chart Category = RecordDate
3. Chart Series = SeriesID (Group/Sort By) and SeriesLabel for the Label
4. Chart Value 1

   - Primary Axis
   - Expression: `=iif(Fields!SeriesID <> 3,Fields!Value.Value,nothing)`
5. Chart Value 2

   - Secondary Axis
   - Expression: `=iif(Fields!SeriesID = 3,Fields!Value.Value,nothing)`
   - Hide Legend for this Axis
6. Set the Line Color for each Chart Value to be conditioned on the SeriesID so the "Total Units" Marker Color in the Primary Axis Legend matches the Line Color on the Secondary Axis. Something like this: `=switch(Fields!SeriesID.Value=1,"Red",Fields!SeriesID.Value=2,"Blue",Fields!SeriesID.Value=3,"Green")`

Here is what we end up with:
[image: Percent / Total Chart]